# Django get JSON object sent from Javascript to Django Views

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I need to pass a Json Object value after making an API call to my views.py in order to render in django template. After making an ajax call  I'm not able to get the value in django`

```
let application = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("appId"));
let kycStatus = application.applicationId

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: `${url}/${kycStatus}`,
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'X-API-Key': '',
        },
        data: {
            senddata: JSON.stringify(),
        },
        success: function(data)  {
            document.getElementById("kyc-status").innerHTML = data.overallResult.status
            console.log(data.overallResult.status)
        }
     

})`
```

in my views.py

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'


def kycsubmit(request):
    """ A view to return the index page"""
    if is_ajax(request=request):
       if request.method == 'GET':
            data = request.GET.get('senddata')
            print(data)
           
    return render(request, 'kycsubmit/onboard.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

the `print` method in `def kycsubmit(request):` will only print in terminal. Use context variable here

```py
def kycsubmit(request):
    """ A view to return the index page"""
    if is_ajax(request=request):
       if request.method == 'GET':
            data = request.GET.get('senddata')
            return render(request, 'kycsubmit/onboard.html',{'data':data})
```

Comment: tbh I'm not even getting printed to the terminal, that's why I'm stuck

Comment: `senddata` on your ajax is a empty `JSON.stringify()`. check this too

Comment: yep you’re right need to pass my data there